# Is it possible to enable a rust feature only in test?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

Say I have crate A, B and I want to share a test helper function `helper()` in crate A to crate B, so I use a feature `test-utils`:

```
#[cfg(feature="test-utils")]
pub fn helper(){

}
```

So the problem is since the helper function contains modification of sensitive data in A, I don't want this function to be compiled in production, such as `cargo build --all-features`.

Is there a way I can enable this feature only in test, and disable it in production？

Comment: It should be possible to enable features in `dev-dependencies`, although I have never checked whether you could have a dependency in both `dependencies` and `dev-dependencies` with different features. Maybe look at that? I don't really see the point though, that is not really what features are for: if somebody wants to misuse `helper` they can enable the feature and *voilà*. Seems to me the helper should rather go into some sort of test utilities submodule.

Comment: You could mark the function as `unsafe`, even if it isn't in the usual Rust sense. This would prevent people from accidentally calling the function. If they are willing to use `unsafe`, they can modify any data in whatever way they want anyway.

Comment: @Masklinn Note that Cargo considers features to be additive. If your dependcy graph contains crate `A` twice, once with feature `foo` enabled and once without, Cargo will include the crate only once, with the feature enabled. This makes, e.g., mutually exclusive features infeasible, and I guess it also rules out the use you suggest, though I haven't tested it.

Comment: @SvenMarnach not sure it would be a problem here: `dev-dependencies` would be enabled while testing but not while doing a regular build right? So the regular build would have a dependency on `A`, and the test build on `A[features=[test-utils]]` which seems to be what OP's looking for. Or am I misunderstanding dev-dependencies?

Answer (score 11):

This is a [requested feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2911#issuecomment-749580481) of Cargo and is only possible using the [version 2 resolver](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/features.html#feature-resolver-version-2). If crate A has the function you mentioned, then crate B's `Cargo.toml` may contain

```
[package]
name = "B"
resolver = "2"

[features]
test-utils = []

[dependencies]
A = "*"

[dev-dependencies]
A = { version = "*", features = ["test-utils"] }
B = { path = ".", features = ["test-utils"] }
```

This would ensure that both crates are built with the `test-utils` feature *only* when testing them. I use to run

```sh
cargo build --release -vv
cargo test --release -vv
```

and make sure I *really* get the features I asked in both cases.